# use of substr in php mysql query syntax

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get just the first character from from column bedroomssvo and am getting the completely helpful "Invalid Syntax" on this query in PHP.  I've tried switching the ` with ' etc and still get the same thing...what am I doing wrong?

```
$query = @mysql_query("SELECT mlnum, , `.substr('bedroomssvo',0,1).`,totalfullbaths, arealiving FROM naples_Single_Family);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I see a couple of issues here:

```
SELECT mlnum, , `.substr('bedroomssvo',0,1).`,totalfullbaths, arealiving 
    FROM naples_Single_Family
```

- You have an extra comma after mlnum.
- `.substr('bedroomssvo',0,1).` means "the column `.substr('bedroomssvo',0,1).`", I don't think you want that.
- `substr` and `substring` have the first character index at 1 in SQL (while in most languages it is 0 indexed)

So the question is, are you trying to get the substring of `'bedroomssvo'` (which will always be `'b'`) or are you trying to get the substring of the column which is named `bedroomssvo`? I suspect the latter is the case. That query would be:

```
SELECT mlnum, substr(bedroomssvo,1,1) as bedroomssvo_first_char,totalfullbaths, 
     arealiving FROM naples_Single_Family
```

Notice how I got rid of all of the quotes, ticks, and `.`'s? That's because you don't need to escape anything and you don't need any funny business surrounding column names. (Aside: the `as bedroomssvo_first_char` is optional, but it makes your output a little easier to understand).

On the other hand, if you want to get the substring of a variable you have access to in PHP, then you can do this:

```
"SELECT mlnum, '{$yourString[0]}',totalfullbaths, arealiving 
    FROM naples_Single_Family"
```

Comment: `pos` starts at 1, not 0 for `substr`.

Comment: Sorry about that. I actually got to that before I saw your comment though.

Answer (score 4):

Please don't do this (`@...`). You're suppressing errors that may be valid.

You also need to stop using `mysql_` functions. They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

You want to use `SUBSTR` like so (position 1 is `1`, not `0`):

```
SELECT mlnum, 
       Substr(bedroomssvo, 1, 1) AS bedroomssvo, 
       totalfullbaths, 
       arealiving 
FROM   naples_single_family
```

[Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substr)

Answer (score 2):

You are using backticks instead of quotes, you dont have to escape a mysql function. This will work.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT mlnum, SUBSTR(bedroomssvo,1,1),totalfullbaths, arealiving FROM naples_Single_Family);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 SELECT mlnum , substr('bedroomssvo',0,1) ,totalfullbaths, arealiving FROM naples_Single_Family
```

if `bedroomssvo` is a column then use it like that

```
SELECT mlnum , substr(bedroomssvo,1,1) ,totalfullbaths, arealiving FROM naples_Single_Family
```

Comment: is this `bedroomssvo` a column ??

Answer (score 1):

use

```
SUBSTR(column_name,1,x)
```

Where:

1. column_name (fieldname)
2. 1: starting index: please not in mysql the starting index is 1
3. x = integer (the length)

use:

```
SUBSTR('text',1,x)
```

For text

REF: [SUBSTR()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substr)